# Autowired singletons in SpringBootTests are not really single. How can this be and how should I handle it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, singleton, autowired, spring-boot-test

I have a SpringBoot application under main/java with tests under test/java.
Some of the tests are annotated with `@SpringBootTest`.

Some of the classes in the application have a field reference to a "Manager" object.
The field is autowired. It is not explicity scoped as prototype and is therefore a singleton.

When I run the tests (I am using gradle) I see that the Manager object is instantiated twice in the same process which came as a surprise.

A possible explanation for this is that each `@SpringBootTest` test fixture represents an application running as a test, and therefore for each test fixture Spring Boot creates all the dependencies required from scratch.

This would be reasonable behavior because none of the tests in one fixture access tests in another fixture, so for all intents and purposes it might seem that the singleton contract has been honored.

The problem however is that all of the test fixtures are instantiated in the same process.
Therefore, any process wide work that is done when the singleton is created leaves side effects for the next test.

In particular, my Manager singleton appends a custom Appender to the logback root logger.
When the tests in the second test fixture run, each log message is emitted twice.

Assuming this behavior is to be expected, what is the best practice to prevent such side effects.
If it is not to be expected, can anyone tell me what I need to do to keep autowired singletons single in the process?

Comment: First it is a singleton **per application context** NOT per application!. Generally the application contexts created by the Spring Test Context Framework are cached. And the cache key is generated from the names of the configuration classes, custom properties, test execution listeners, active profiles etc. if one of those is different in any test a new application context will be launched. Another thing to think of is proxying, cglib creates an "empty" instance of the class and extends it, wrapping the actual instance of the class. Leading to 2 instances of that class.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for this clarification.
So in order to create an environment that behaves as a process wide singleton, I should use my own tools. For instance state held in a static variable? In the particular case above I needed the appender to be process wide single so I implemented a specific solution which sets the name of the appender and does not add it to the root logger if one with the same name already exists.
Does that sound like a reasonable solution for my case?